# obtain listValue of selected item in <s:select> in struts2

Tags: javascript, struts2

I have a JSP page which uses an `<s:select>` tag.

```
<s:select 
        id="userGroups"
        headerKey="-1"
        headerValue="------ Select Group ------" list="userGroupList"
        listValue="groupName"
        onchange="selectGroup()">
```

what i want to achieve is to display the listValue of the selected item using a javascript function. what may be the way to do this?

EDIT: my selectGroup() function:

```
function selectGroup(){
    var selectedGroup = document.getElementById('userGroups');
    alert(selectedGroup.value);
}
```

Comment: Post your `selectGroup` function.

Comment: i have posted the selectGroup() function in an EDIT

Comment: I have similar function and it is working fine till IE 8. But from IE 9 it is returning header value instead of selected item value. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function selectGroup(){
    var sel = document.getElementById('userGroups');
    alert(sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text);
}
```

or

```
<s:select 
    id="userGroups"
    headerKey="-1"
    headerValue="------ Select Group ------" list="userGroupList"
    listValue="groupName"
    onchange="selectGroup(this)"> 

function selectGroup(sel){
    alert(sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text);
}
```

or

```
<s:select 
    id="userGroups"
    headerKey="-1"
    headerValue="------ Select Group ------" list="userGroupList"
    listValue="groupName"
    onchange="alert(this.options[this.selectedIndex].text);">
```

Comment: You are welcome. Why don't you upvote btw ? 44 questions, 5 upvotes :) StackOverflow won't charge you anything, it's 100% free, I swear :P

Comment: well i upvote everytime i get the solution to my problem. others are waiting for solutions. i am trying them on simultaneously. i personally think that upvoting helps a lot..:)

Comment: `well i upvote everytime i get the solution to my problem.` If it works like a charm, isn't this a solution to your problem ? :) I don't get the other part of your comment :O

Comment: That is *accepting* an answer. Upvoting is pressing the upward arrow to express the answer (or the question) is adding some value to the discussion. You can accept only one answer, but upvoting how many answers / questions you want...